# Youtube LiveStreaming API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to create a website where each user can create/start live streaming.
But as I can see for now I can only create a stream for my own account. The one in which Youtube Data API is enabled. The one which secret keys are written in code. So I have no permissions to create live stream from someones account.
My question is if it is possible to do with Youtube API or not?

**UPDATE**

I found the way to add broadcast to user's account. But I can't understand how to tell user how to stream to created broadcast. He needs stream_key. (As I know...cause I use OBS software for windows and the only thing I need is `stream_key` to start streaming.

Comment: If memory serves accounts have to be enabled to use live stream.  Even if you authenticate your users their still gong to have to enable live streaming on their account

Comment: Thanks. I found the way to add broadcast to user's account. But I can't understand how to tell user how to stream to created broadcast. He needs `stream_key`. (As I know...cause I use OBS software for windows and the only thing I need is stream_key to start streaming.

Comment: If you get it working please answer your question I would like to see it :)

Comment: I found out. I need to choose Custom Streaming Server in OBS. And in this case I need URL and Stream Key. Which I can get from 
`$streamsResponse['modelData']['cdn']['ingestionInfo']['streamName']` and `$streamsResponse['modelData']['cdn']['ingestionInfo']['ingestionAddress']`.

Comment: If you post it as an answer you will get points :)

Comment: I'm new here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found out myself. If somebody has same question...
I need to choose Custom Streaming Server in OBS. And in this case I need URL and Stream Key. Which I can get from `$streamsResponse['modelData']['cdn']['ingestionInfo']['strea‌​mName']` and `$streamsResponse['modelData']['cdn']['ingestionInfo']['inges‌​tionAddress']`

Comment: How to start the streaming and how to get youtube video url ? Please help !

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit more advanced than using OBS, but you could use Wowza's GoCoder livestreaming SDK to build a mobile app. Your subscribers/users can generate a livestream from their mobile phones > to Wowza Media Server > final stream target destination configured for You Tube live.

It works directly with the You Tube Live API.